# no-unused-vars en react con componente importado y usado

Tags: reactjs, jsx

estoy intentando crear una paginacion como parte de un proyecto, creo el componente, lo importo y uso con las propiedades y al intentar correr el Código me dice que esta definido pero no usado
el error no debería ser de tipeo pues el nombre del componente al importarlo y usarlo son copiados y ya intente re hacerlo varias veces

```
import paginacionComponente from './paginacion'

function App() {
  
const [paginaActual,setPaginaActual] = useState(1);

  return (
    <PageWrapper>
      {/* peliculasInfoJson.map hace que la función flecha pelicula revise los arrays y sus elementos y los devuelva segun la estructura del componente peliculaComponente 
      (es como un for/foreach pero devuelve elemntos)*/}



      {peliculasInfoJson.map(pelicula =>
      (
        
        <PeliculaComponente titulo={pelicula.titulo} calificación={pelicula.calificación}
          duración={pelicula.duración} clasificación={pelicula.clasificación} lanzamiento={pelicula.lanzamiento} director={pelicula.director} actor1={pelicula.actor1} actor2={pelicula.actor2}
          actor3={pelicula.actor3}
          img={pelicula.img} descripción={pelicula.descripción} sarasa={pelicula.sarasa} >
        </PeliculaComponente>

     )
      )}
      <paginacionComponente actual={paginaActual} total={4} onChange={(actual) => { setPaginaActual(actual) }} />

    </PageWrapper>


  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: El nombre del componente debe ir en uppercase letter `Paginacioncomponente `

Comment: ahi funcionó, gracias